# SVN commit only works when connected via ssh

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I really don't know how this started but for some strange reason I can only do a commit when I connect to my server via ssh (using putty). This all worked fine before.

I am using ubuntu 2.6.28-16-server

I think this all started after a few updates :(

Comment: How did it *used* to work?  That could be a relevant diagnostic detail.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your SVN server is configured to use SSH (if you are not sure check the URL, does it begin with ssh) - in such a case it could be that your key has gotten corrupted or a setting is broken (which did the stuff automatically before).

Easiest is just to run the putty configuration tool, on the *Sessions* window select your *Saved Session* and hit *Load*. Then go to *Connection* -> *SSH* and check the settings, taking special notice of the *Private key file for authentication* under *Auth*

Comment: You might need to re-read the question... "I can **only** do a commit when I connect to my server via ssh"

Comment: @Womble - I got that part fine. What I suspect is that it was always establishing the SSH tunnel, albeit automatically in the background as the SVN system was doing it automatically. Now that the settings are broken, and unless he establishes a tunnel manually it fails.